# Match several full HTML paragraphs containing text inside brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I need to match full HTML paragraphs which contain text between triple curly brackets.

Here is my input HTML:

```
<p><strong>{{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</strong></p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor}}}</p>
<p><em>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</em></p>
<p><strong><em>Sed {{{ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</em></strong><em> sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</em></p>
<p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.}}}</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.</p>
```

The following fragments should be matched:

```
<p><strong>{{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</strong></p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor}}}</p>
```

and

```
<p><strong><em>Sed {{{ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</em></strong><em> sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</em></p>
<p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.}}}</p>
```

Currently I'm trying to use the following regex:

`<p>.*?{{{.*?}}}<\/p>/gms`

Apparently, it doesn't work properly.

Here is a Regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/9NSMy3/2

I know that it's not the best idea to use regex for parsing HTML, so any other solutions are also highly appreciated.

Comment: What paragraphs do you want to include? All paragraphs from the first {{{ to the last }}} found?

Comment: No. From the first {{{ to the next }}}. Then, from the next {{{ found to the next }}}. And so on.

Comment: Would this only be done with this html fragment or with a larger document?

Comment: @QHarr in real life it will be done with larger HTML documents, but with the same syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser to find all `p` elements, check each one for a match with the `in` operator, and store matches in a list. Here I'm checking whether a set of opening brackets has been previously seen (to keep track of an on-going match) with the `begin` flag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inputhtml = '''
<p><strong>{{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</strong></p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor}}}</p>
<p><em>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</em></p>
<p><strong><em>Sed {{{ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</em></strong><em> sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</em></p>
<p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.}}}</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(inputhtml,'html.parser')

fragments = []
begin = False
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    if '{{{' in p.text:
        begin = True
        fragments.append(str(p))
    if '}}}' in p.text:
        begin = False
    if '}}}' in p.text and not '{{{' in p.text:
        fragments[-1] += str(p)
    elif begin and not '{{{' in p.text and not '}}}' in p.text:
        fragments[-1] += str(p)

print(fragments)
```

Output:

```
['<p><strong>{{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</strong></p><p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p><p>Duis aute irure dolor}}}</p>',
'<p><strong><em>Sed {{{ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</em></strong><em> sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</em></p><p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.}}}</p>']
```

Comment: Ooops, just found out that it's not doing what it should. The first fragment must be `<p><strong>{{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</strong></p><p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p><p>Duis aute irure dolor}}}</p>` - it's THREE paragraphs, where the first one contains `{{{`, the last one contains `}}}`, and the middle one is just in the middle :)